# Windows security alert

Tags: windows-10, firewall

When I boot up my PC, I get these windows security alert message telling me to allow the programs and I have configured to open on startup through the firewall, then if I open an application E.G Steam, it gives me the same message, so I press allow, but the next time I boot the application or PC, they show up again, I've done a virus scan with Malwarebytes to no avail. I am using windows 10

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: unfourchantly uninstalling tunnelbear has done nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you do have TunnelBear installed I am assuming you have the same issue as me.

TunnelBear installs a service named TunnelBear Maintenance (the exact service name is TunnelBearMaintenance).

It seems that when this service is running it somehow manages to remove every **non predefined** rule (or every rule with a blank group) from the Windows Firewall Inbound/Outbound rules lists.

Stopping this service will give you the old (expected) behavior back but you will have to Allow Access in the Windows Security Alert again for every application that requests network access one more time.

To stop the service press **Start** and search for **Services** and open it. Then search for the service **TunnelBear Maintenance** (just start typing it). Right-click -> Properties. Press the **Stop** button and then also change the **Startup type** to **Manual**. This will only start the service when you start TunnelBear.

However, every time that you start the service it will remove all rules mentioned above so you will have to stop the service manually (or it will stop automatically after a system restart) and you will have to Allow Access in the Windows Security Alert again for every application that requests network access one more time.

Comment: yeah, i uninstalled tunnelbear yesterday, no results... but today, seems to be working fine!

Comment: @Antp: I guess the uninstaller removed the service as well and then just a restart was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom inbound/outbound rule for Windows's Firewall for certain application and see if it still happens.

1. Launch "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".
2. Under "Inbound Rules", select "New Rule".
3. Check "Program" under Rule Type.

[image]

4.Set the program path.

[image]

5. Allow the connection and set the appropriate profile for the rule.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Windows is identifying the network you connect to as a "Public" network, hence the pop up every time.  Change your network type from public to private.

Change network type from public to private:

https://tinkertry.com/how-to-change-windows-10-network-type-from-public-to-private

Comment: How do i do this?

Comment: Added link above

Comment: https://tinkertry.com/how-to-change-windows-10-network-type-from-public-to-private

Comment: It's private now, but it's still giving me alerts when I open an application.

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: no, i do have one installed, but am not using it

Comment: Control Panel > System and Security > Security and Maintenance > Turn off messages about firewall

Comment: I can't find "turn off messages about firewall"

Comment: it in the Security and Maintenance Control Panel on the left hand side "change security and maintenance settings" Uncheck  Network Firewall

Comment: @BrokeBytes You should include detailed instructions in the answer instead of pointing readers to a URL, but if you do, quote and cite the relevant information from the site

Comment: message still popping up

Comment: “Windows is identifying the network you connect to as a "Public" network” It’s not. Otherwise, the “Public” checkbox would be checked when the dialog opens.