# Windows Security Alerts keeps popup

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-firewall

Every time I ran an app a windows security alert pops up.

It doesn't matter which button to press, it will appear next time anyway.

I tried to disable all messages and even turn off windows firewall, but it doesn't help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you have recieved is a UAC prompt.  The notifications your disabling  are something else entirely.  Have you added the exception rule to the Windows Firewall in order to avoid the UAC prompt?  *Doing so requires you to authenticate as an Administrator.*

Comment: I've found the solution. I have a TunnelBear installed. Disabling one of his services resolves the problem. «TunnelBear installs a service named TunnelBear Maintenance (the exact service name is TunnelBearMaintenance).

It seems that when this service is running it somehow manages to remove every non predefined rule (or every rule with a blank group) from the Windows Firewall Inbound/Outbound rules lists.» [link](http://superuser.com/questions/1130209/windows-security-alert)

Comment: So this message pops up even if you have windows firewall disabled on all connections - private, public and domain? Domain might not there if the computer is not part of domain.
Because this message is normally OK. It basically asks you, if you want to create a firewall rule to enable traffic on particular connection type for this application (in your case chrome).
You can check the connection type in network and sharing center. If you tick box for that connection type in the dialog which comes up it should create the rule and never pop up again for that particular application.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is related to a program called TunnelBear. As mentioned in this question (with terrible header) [Windows security alert](https://superuser.com/questions/1130209/windows-security-alert)

«TunnelBear installs a service named TunnelBear Maintenance (the exact service name is TunnelBearMaintenance).

It seems that when this service is running it somehow manages to remove every non predefined rule (or every rule with a blank group) from the Windows Firewall Inbound/Outbound rules lists.

Stopping this service will give you the old (expected) behavior back but you will have to Allow Access in the Windows Security Alert again for every application that requests network access one more time.

To stop the service press Start and search for Services and open it. Then search for the service TunnelBear Maintenance (just start typing it). Right-click -> Properties. Press the Stop button and then also change the Startup type to Manual. This will only start the service when you start TunnelBear.

However, every time that you start the service it will remove all rules mentioned above so you will have to stop the service manually (or it will stop automatically after a system restart) and you will have to Allow Access in the Windows Security Alert again for every application that requests network access one more time.» Ma3x

Comment: The proper course of action, when you realize another question which has an answer is a duplicate of your own question, is to flag your question as a duplicate of that question.